# Change only color when changing Theme

Tags: android, android-resources, android-theme, android-styles, android-color

I want to support different themes in my android application.
The themes should only differ in two colors. So there are these colors for every theme:

- Primary Color
- Secondary Color

What I want is, that there is one big default theme, that also has children like button styles et, like this (styles.xml):

```
<style name="DefaultTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/my_stackoverflow_arrow</item>
    [...]
</style>

<style name="DefaultTheme.NoActionBar">
    <!-- hide action bar and title -->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="DefaultTheme.Button">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    [...]
</style>
```

But now I also want to change themes for different colors. Therefore, I have created a resource in the `attrs.xml` file:

```
<resources>
    <attr name="ThemeColorPrimary" format="reference" />
    <attr name="ThemeColorSecondary" format="reference" />
</resources>
```

So now I can use this attribute in my `styles.xml` from above like this:

```
<style name="DefaultTheme.Button">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?attr/ThemeColorPrimary</item>
    [...]
</style>
```

But how do I create my colored themes? I know I need to do something like this:

```
<item name="ThemeColorPrimary">@color/ThemeBluePrimary</item>
```

But where? And which theme inherits from which? If I now have something like:

```
<style name="BlueTheme" parent="DefaultTheme">
    <item name="ThemeColorPrimary">@color/ThemeBluePrimary</item>
    <item name="ThemeColorSecondary">@color/ThemeBlueSecondary</item>
</style>

<style name="GreyTheme" parent="DefaultTheme">
    <item name="ThemeColorPrimary">@color/ThemeGreyPrimary</item>
    <item name="ThemeColorSecondary">@color/ThemeGreySecondary</item>
</style>

<style name="BlackTheme" parent="DefaultTheme">
    <item name="ThemeColorPrimary">@color/ThemeBlackPrimary</item>
    <item name="ThemeColorSecondary">@color/ThemeBlackSecondary</item>
</style>
```

I can't specify in `AndroidManifest.xml` the theme like this:

```
<activity
    android:name="StackOverflowActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/DefaultTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

Because the specified resources would be missing. Otherwise I also can't to this:

```
<activity
    android:name="StackOverflowActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/BlueTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

because BlueTheme has no Child that is called "NoActionBar".

I know this is confusing, I am pretty confused myself.
How can I solve this?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify those custom attributes in the parent theme:

```
<style name="DefaultTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="ThemeColorPrimary">@color/defaultPrimaryColor</item>
    <item name="ThemeColorSecondary">@color/defaultSecondaryColor</item>
</style>
```

Then each children of `DefaultTheme` would have access to your custom attributes and also can override those.

If you want to combine `NoActionBar` and `BlueTheme`, then you have to subclass `NoActionBar` theme:

```
<style name="BlueNoActionBarTheme" parent="DefaultTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="ThemeColorPrimary">@color/ThemeBluePrimary</item>
    <item name="ThemeColorSecondary">@color/ThemeBlueSecondary</item>
</style>
```